# Eslint arrow function, expected to have type annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint

so I have the following code:

```
public someFunctionName = (someParam: someType): void => {
    ...some code
};
```

When I run eslint on the file I get the error: `expected someFunctionName to have a type annotation`.

The only way that I can find to solve this is to remove the arrow function and replace with a regular function.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem for arrow functions?

Comment: is this a function for a class?  If is there a specific reason why you want to do an arrow function as opposed to traditional?

Answer (score 2):

Type-defining the function signature may help:

```
type SomeFuncType = (a: number) => void;

const someFunc: SomeFuncType = (a: number): void => {
  //
};
```

Also helps when exporting callback types.

I've recently dropped all uses of *tslint*, and adopted *typescript-eslint* instead. This includes removal of the VS Code *tslint* extension. *Prettier* is pretty much my choice these days.